# Generating data with given median from empirical data

Tags: distributions, simulation, approximation

I have an empirical distribution of household income based on the US census from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_income_in_the_United_States#Distribution_of_household_income_in_2014_according_to_US_Census_data) and I'd like to generate a plausible distribution for the income distribution in a region given its median income.

To be concrete, here's a schematic of the income CDF:

```
Income  | Percentile
20k     | 20th
40k     | 40th
60k     | 50th
80k     | 70th
100k    | 80th
120k    | 90th
200k    | 95th
```

It's pretty straightforward to generate a distribution with manipulated median by setting a cutoff. For example, one distribution corresponding to a median income of 40k (the 40th percentile of the distribution for the entire US) would set the maximum of the income CDF at 100k, throw out everyone above the 80th percentile, and re-scale the data to look like this:

```
Income  | Percentile
20k     | 25th
40k     | 50th
60k     | 63rd
80k     | 87th
100k    | MAX
```

That distribution is probably "good enough" to learn something, but the idea of setting a cutoff doesn't sit well with me from the common-sense standpoint (i.e. there are some quite-wealthy people almost everywhere, and there are some quite-impoverished people almost everywhere). Is there a recommended way to massage the data back towards the original distribution without disturbing the median; and is there a justification for your method?

Comment: That's a fair criticism, but I think there's a lot of possibilities that have strong Bayesian justification given that the distribution that this data was drawn from is known.

Comment: The distribution is the empirical distribution of the US income data.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you. But still, you are assuming that the distribution in each region is the same as nation-wide distribution -- this does not have to be true.

Comment: The term massage the data has a bad connotation.  Literally I think it means modifying the data to achieve some purpose.  I hope that is not what you mean.  If you suspect errors in the data deleting outliers for a robustness goal might be acceptable if the outlier(s) could be expected  and you have reason to know  that such extreme values are likely to be errors.

Comment: In a low-information context like this one (inferring an entire distribution from its median and an empirical distribution that it likely, approximately follows), the term "massage" feels appropriate. In my opinion, the answer recommending approximating with an exponential distribution is reasonable, but I'd argue it still makes sizable-enough assumptions to be considered "massaging" the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can expect a variable like income to have an exponential distribution, most people have a low income and progressively fewer people have larger incomes. A benefit of using this distribution is that it cannot be negative but it can be arbitrarily close to \$0. To fix this, set a minimum income like 10k and consider an exponential distribution added on to the minimum income.

An exponential distribution has one parameter, the rate $\lambda$. The median of an exponential distribution is $\frac{ln(2)}{\lambda}$

So if the median income is 60k (50k above the minimum) then the rate is $\lambda = \frac{ln(2)}{50000}$

With this figure the distribution of income is:

- 0th percentile = 10k
- 10th percentile = 18k
- 20th percentile = 26k
- 30th percentile = 36k
- 40th percentile = 47k
- 50th percentile = 60k
- 60th percentile = 76k
- 70th percentile = 97k
- 80th percentile = 126k
- 90th percentile = 176k
- 95th percentile = 226k

If $p$ is the percentile then you can calculate these incomes with the formula: $\text{income} = \frac{-ln(1 - p)}{\lambda} + \text{minimum income}$

Comment: That's a clever choice. I'll take a look and see how good of a fit it is to the empirical data. Interestingly enough, the median US income is 55k, and the average is about 75k, which is pretty close to a factor of 1/ln(2) more. Shifting the distribution up by 10k almost nails the numbers.

Comment: This bothers me because the concept of fitting the data to a distribution seems to be lost. What is the wikipedia data?  Is it just an empirical distirbution of income nationwide without regard to region of the country?  If so you don't have information by region I see no basis to accept the model.  Without knowing the median income for the regions how can you construct a fitted distribution to the empirical data.